# TypeError: tick_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

After running this code:

```py
mplot.Axes.tick_params(fontfamily="Century Gothic",fontsize=15,labelsize=20,)
```

I have the following error message:

```
    line 30, in <module>
        mplot.Axes.tick_params(fontfamily="Century Gothic",fontsize=15,labelsize=20)
    TypeError: tick_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What should I do?

Comment: You need an *instance* of `mplot.Axes` first.

Comment: Even if - [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) does not accept the keyword `fontfamily`.